# Глобальные переменные и JavaScript

Tags: javascript, производительность

Влияют ли глобальные переменные в js (т.е. переменные объявленные не в методах) на производительность скрипта?

И если да, то как исправить штук 100 скриптов, в которых есть такие переменные?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще, на производительность скрипта - не влияют, а на производительность программиста - да.
Исправить можно только перегнав переменные в свойства объекта и параметры функций. В общем случае. В некоторых частных - просто удалить.

Comment: Просто, если не влияет, то смысла убирать не вижу :)
А если да, то нужно убирать...

Comment: Рано или поздно увидите, но потом будет поздно...

Comment: В своих-то скриптах я всегда пишу локальные переменные, просто проект "полуготовый" подбросили, вот теперь мучаюсь... хоть вообще всё переписывай :(

Comment: тогда я бы не переписывал, работал бы с тем что есть т.к. вашему работодателю скорее всего пофиг используются ли глобальные перменные или нет, ему важно чтобы "как-то" работало.<br>
Я сам не раз работал с страшными быдлокодами, по началу тоже пытался что-то править и т.д., по опыту - толку от этого мало...<br>
А еще лучше сообщить работодателя о том что есть такое вот горе и еге можно исправить, обьяснить что это как и т.д., у меня 2 раза в подобных ситуациях уже соглашались, но обычно клиентам плевать как оно написано...

Comment: о, очередная экономия на спичках.

ЗЫ: Писать изначально правильно нужно

Comment: причем тут спички? в javascript и так проблемы с видимостью свойств и полей (в плане privat, public и т.д.), огромное количество глобальных переменных лишь усугубляет эту проблему превращая код в свалку, это не економия на спичках...<br>
Сразу видно как "много" у вас опыта работы с js...

Comment: @shurik, как вам такой спичечный домик???
http://saveimg.ru/show-image.php?id=b7fe95bec5212b68c119ba05b9e00f94

Comment: >> (в плане privat, public и т.д.)

в JS этого попросту нет. 
У человека нету проблем с кодом, ему не нужно ничего доделывать/переделывать, он желает лишь "оптимизировать" работу JS кода. Причем тут вообще эти (в плане privat, public и т.д.) ?

По поводу "много" опыта я могу лишь посмеяться :) Спасибо улыбнули.

Comment: Из моего опыта и общих соображений (конкретно про js не скажу) глобальные переменные только ускоряют скрипт. 

Но !!!! Они могут **сильно замедлить** внедрение изменений.

Comment: если проблема строго в производительности то вообще нет необходимости что либо переписывать<br>
@shurik спасибо за то что разьяснили, ато я жил и не знал что в js этого нет, кагбы мой коммент продолжение того что написано выше и кагбы надо учится читать все а не вылавливать неугодные вам фразы и умничать на пустом месте ;)<br>
Поправьте если я гдето не прав... А что смешного то? Если бы у вас был большой опыт вы бы тка скептично не относились бы к проблемам глобальности и приватности в javascript, лишь делаю выводы из написаного вами, не более. Рад что вам было смешно :)

Comment: >> Поправьте если я гдето не прав

Пересмотрите вопросы топикстертера. Я не думаю что проблема столь актуальна как вы её себе представляете. Пересмотрите, я думаю, вы сами все поймете...

Comment: Вот только топикстартер, к сожалению, не понял... разъясните?